# Option wsdlArtifact in cxf-codegen-plugin on different modules

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin

there is a strange behavior with the cxf-codegen-plugin on maven.

Some informations:

One parent pom (called PARENT) with 3 children: SERVICE, CLIENT1, CLIENT2.

The service generate two wsdl described by two classifiers starting from two classes. The SERVICE pom.xml is:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-client-first</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>first</classifier>
                        <className>com.CLASS1</className>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <attachWsdl>true</attachWsdl>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java2ws</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-client-second</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>second</classifier>
                        <className>com.CLASS2</className>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <attachWsdl>true</attachWsdl>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java2ws</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

CLIENT1 and 2 generate two java client starting from the classified wsdl produced in SERVICE. Thus CLIENT1 pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-sources-client1</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
          <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
              <wsdlArtifact>
                <groupId>com.something</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>first</classifier>
              </wsdlArtifact>
            </wsdlOption>
          </wsdlOptions>
          <defaultOptions>
            <faultSerialVersionUID>FQCN</faultSerialVersionUID>
          </defaultOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

CLIENT2 pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-sources-client2</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
          <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
              <wsdlArtifact>
                <groupId>com.something</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <classifier>second</classifier>
              </wsdlArtifact>
            </wsdlOption>
          </wsdlOptions>
          <defaultOptions>
            <faultSerialVersionUID>FQCN</faultSerialVersionUID>
          </defaultOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Running just the CLIENT2 pom (***mvn -U clean install***) everything works properly, as far as running the goal ***mvn -U generate-sources*** on the PARENT pom.

The problem occurs running: ***mvn -U clean install*** on parent pom, because the second client is not generated: in fact it "resolves" always the first wsdl:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building client2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ client2 ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/developer/workspace/PARENT/CLIENT2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.4:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ client2 ---
[INFO] com.something:artifact:wsdl:first:1.0-SNAPSHOT resolved to /home/.../Class1.wsdl
[INFO] Resolved WSDL artifact to file /home/.../Class1.wsdl
```

The problem is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974146/cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdlartifact-multiple-executions), because in that case there were 2 executions in a single build. Last two info: 
1) I have this problem on local while on Jenkins everything works properly.
2) Maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: /opt/develop/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-46-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!